# I get a strange search result when searching a couple of collections, but others are as they should be

Tags: magento2.4, search, security, search-terms

It's puzzling.

For example, when I search for "classic", I get a strange search result:

> Related search terms
> classic style 394
> classic') AND 6096 IN (SELECT
> (CHAR(113)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(120)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(113)+(SELECT (CASE WHEN
> (6096=6096) THEN CHAR(49) EL
> classic' AND 6096 IN (SELECT
> (CHAR(113)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(120)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(113)+(SELECT (CASE WHEN
> (6096=6096) THEN CHAR(49) ELS
> classic AND 6096 IN (SELECT
> (CHAR(113)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(120)+CHAR(106)+CHAR(113)+(SELECT (CASE WHEN
> (6096=6096) THEN CHAR(49) ELSE
> classic style 356

> classic') AND 9254=CAST((CHR(113)||CHR(106)||CHR(120)||CHR(106)||CHR(113))||(SELECT (CASE WHEN (9254=9254) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::
> classic') AND 6791=(SELECT UPPER(XMLType(CHR(60)||CHR(58)||CHR(113)||CHR(106)||CHR(120)||CHR(106)||CHR(113)||(SELECT (CASE WHEN
> classic') AND 2093=2093 AND ('lBbC'='lBbC

weird: https://pegeen.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=classic

normal: https://pegeen.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=everyday

Magento 2.x

Answer (score 0):

They are search terms that users enter to search on your Magento site.

**The root cause**: Someone tried to find vulnerabilities to attack your Magento site by adding SQL injection queries to the search terms.

If your Magento version matches one of the following, your site is safe and you can ignore these search terms:

- The latest Magento version 2.4.5-p1
- 2.4.5 and already applied security hotfix for [CVE-2022-35698](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html)
- 2.4.4-p2 and already applied security hotfix for [CVE-2022-35698](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html)
- 2.4.3-p3 and already applied security hotfix for [CVE-2022-35698](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/adobe-commerce-2.4.3-p2-2.4.5-security-hotfix-for-cve-2022-35698.html)

If your Magento does not match one of the above versions, you should **upgrade** your Magento site asap.

Note: Magento (Adobe Commerce) 2.4.0-2.4.3 will reach [the end of support](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/planning/lifecycle-policy.html) on November 28, 2022 (2 weeks remaining).

**To removing these strange search terms** from your search result page, taking the following steps:

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Marketing > SEO & Search > Search Terms.
2. In the Search Terms grid, filtering by **Search Query** (for example filtering with **select** text) to get unexpected search terms records.
3. Select unexpected search term records and choose the Delete action.
4. Clear the `config` cache type.

Answer (score 0):

When a user enters a search term this search term is saved in a data base table and later based on popularity this term is used by Ajax search.

In your case some one tried hacking by adding some sql injection to the search query.

This search query is saved in Db hence when some one searches for classic due to match of string the hacked query is considered as a probable search term and displayed.

You should go to the table : `search_query`   and check for classic string and delete those entries and then do a check.

Select * FROM `search_query` WHERE 'query_text' LIKE '%classic%'  and see whats displayed.
Delete FROM `search_query` WHERE 'query_text' LIKE '%classic%'  and then again check if the garbage suggestion in search has gone or not.